# What is the vanilla ES6 equivalent of jQuery's $.when() for promises?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, es6-promise

What is the non-jQuery equivalent of [$.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) for regular promises?
If there is one. If not, how might one implement it? I looked at the jQuery [source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/fcc9a9ec9685e25864ca793698e4ac5e60226272/src/deferred.js) to get an idea, and it seems manageable, but I'd rather not write it myself if there exists a standard implementation already.

Comment: You mean Promises?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: `Promise.all()` is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Promise.all()` is what you're seeking.

```
Promise.all([
  promise1,
  promise2
]).then(/* do something */);
```

Documentation:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Thank you Brad. They should really add this on http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ .
I think I'll suggest it to them.

Comment: Looking at the documentation for `$.when()`, it seems more like `(...args) => Promise.all(args)`